# Отображение логов в LogCat Eclipse при тестировании на устройстве

Tags: android-adb, eclipse

Как можно подключить устройство к LogCat Eclipse, что бы там отображались его логи? 
Т.е. я тестирую приложение на реальном устройстве, подключенном по USB. В LogCat ничего не пишется. Как это исправить и возможно ли вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустите приложение, которое называется monitor (идет в поставке sdk). Слева будет выбор устройств - обязательно выберите свое. Если sdk древнее, то используйте приложение ddms.